# Host multiple MEAN stack apps on same server using Nginx proxy_pass

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, angular-cli, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two MEAN(angular-8) stack apps that need to be deployed in one server. I'm using nginx server in Windows server 2012 environment. The two applications are running perfectly in two ports: servername:port1, servername:port2. In need to access them using urls servername/app1, servername/app2.
Here is my nginx config

```
       location /app1 {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass   http://servername:port1/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
       location /app2 {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass   http://servername:port2/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Here is my node js code part

```
app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, '../dist/' ) ) );
app.use( require( './routes' ) );
app.get( '*', function ( req, res ) {
  return res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, '../dist/index.html' ) )
} )
app.listen( port, () => console.log( 'listening on port ' + port ) );
```

Configuration in angular.json

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

When I try to access the port using servername/app1 it shows blank page. because the js files and css files are not loaded. They are tring to access static files from servername/styles.e9d2ee815fd5ee75430e.css instead of servername/app1/styles.e9d2ee815fd5ee75430e.css

I have tried using try_files in nginx conf,deployUrl --app1 during angular build, and tried using other server(apache) but nothing worked.

How this problem can be solved?

How can I solve the issue?.

Comment: Your Angular app must call url with prefix /app1 or /app2 as well as your static files in express.js must have same prefix `app.use( '/app1', [express.static( path.join( __dirname, '../dist/' )] ) );`

Comment: How to add url prefix in angular app, is it by adding the prefix with deploy url.(--deployUrl /app/)?

Comment: to add prefix url or base url you can just use --base-href with ng build --prod --base-href /<project_name>/

Comment: I have tried ng build --prod --base-href /<project_name>/ as well as  ng build --prod --deploy-url /<project_name>/ , both of them didnt resolve the issue.